# Dynamically changing textColor of a UITableViewCell's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewController` that has one row, and only two `UITableViewCell`s.

I'm trying to dynamically set the color of my `UITableViewCell`'s text (`cell.textLabel.textColor`) based upon a few things:

1) If this is the first time launching, the first cell's text color should be `[UIColor whiteColor]`, and the second cell's text color should be `[UIColor grey1Color]`

2) If the user selects a cell and leaves the screen and then returns to the table-view, the last selected cell's text color should be `[UIColor whiteColor]`, and text color of the cell that was not selected should be `[UIColor grey1Color]`.

Whenever a cell is selected, a property is updated; `myCellTextValue`. This is done to make a few API calls outside of this particular table-view.

My idea for implementing the logic above was to use this property for determining what color the cell's text should be. My code attempt below is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
 if (cell.textLabel.text == self.myCellTextValue) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grey1Color];
    }
 }
```

However, both cell's text color is always grey. I'm sure this mostly has to do with misunderstanding `UITableViewCell` creation in someway. Does anyone have any pointers on how to implement this properly? Thank you!

EDIT: Following @Gismay's comment below, I tried the code below; but got the same result:

```
if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:self.myCellTextValue]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grey1Color];
}
```

EDIT 2: I also tried wrapping the code above in a check to make sure we're only looking at one cell at a time, but this had no effect either:

```
if((indexPath.section==0)&&(indexPath.row==0)){
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:self.myCellTextValue]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grey1Color];
    }
} else if((indexPath.section==0)&&(indexPath.row==1)){
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:self.myCellTextValue]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grey1Color];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your if statement is working? cell.textLabel.text is a string, so surely the comparison should be isEqualToString?

Comment: @Gismay That's a good point. I tried that just now; see my edit above

Comment: is self.myCellTextValue static ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri No, it changes based on whatever cell the user selects

Comment: then in that case, the if condiiton gets executed everytime and cell color will always be grey.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Ah. Yes, that would make sense, thanks! What would be the best way to go about solving this then?

Comment: are u planning to give diff color to each cell text ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri basically yes, if one cell was selected, then that cell's text needs to be white. If a cell wasn't selected, then it's text needs to be grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use selectedRowIndex as a class-level variable, and just keep updating that every time you select a row.  Initially - whether selected or not - this should be 0, so that the first row is different

I think you don't want to use the text value because it may not be unique

What happens when you make multiple selections without leaving the view?  Presumably you need to clear the white text from the old row, and set it again on the new one?

Easiest way to implement that is going to be reloading the tableView on each selection - but if that takes too long, you could always reload the individual rows - on row selection set selectedRowIndexPrevious before you update selectedRowIndex, and reload both of those rows.  The previous row will  redraw in grey, and the new one in white

here's how you might implement some of this

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    // define the variables to keep track of row selection here
    var selectedRowIndex : Int = 0
    var selectedRowIndexPrevious : Int = -1

    // the rest of your code
```

and then you need to update the selectedRow variables

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        // Uncheck the previous checked row
        selectedRowIndexPrevious = selectedRowIndex

        //  **UPDATED** need to set the selectedRowIndex
        selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
        //  **UPDATED**

        //  reload needs an array of indexPath 
        //  so we can supply the previous selection AND the current one

        NSIndexPath* rowToReloadPrevious = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: selectedRowIndexPrevious inSection:0];
        NSIndexPath* rowToReloadNew = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: selectedRowIndex inSection:0];
        NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReloadPrevious, rowToReloadNew, nil];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
   }
```

within the cellForRowAtIndexPath, you just need to look at selectedRowIndex instead of checking the text

```
if (indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grey1Color];
}
```

}

Comment: Hey @Russell! In response to your point about text value not being unique; that's a good point. Would it be better to check for each row then? 

Also a good point about clearing out old text and redrawing.

I'm not sure what you mean by using `selectedRowIndex` as a class-level variable, what would that look like?

Comment: @narner - I have updated the answer.  Hope this gives you what you need

Comment: thanks, this is super super close. Right now though what happens is the first cell will always be white, and the second one will always  be grey. Maybe need a `deselectRowForIndexPath` somewhere?

Comment: odd - is selectedRowIndex being set in the didSelectRow method?  is reload being called for the right rows - what happens if you add a print(indexPath.row) to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: when I add the log, I get the following output when I navigate to the table-view screen: 

`indexPath.row is 0
indexPath.row is 1
indexPath.row is 0
indexPath.row is 1`

And, `selectedRowIndex` is being set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:
`selectedRowIndexPrevious = selectedRowIndex;`

Those are declared above my implementation like so: 

`int selectedRowIndex = 0;
int selectedRowIndexPrevious = -1;

@implementation ViewController`

Comment: I have updated the answer - I just noticed that I didn't include the bit where we actually set a value for selectedRowIndex.  We need that :-)

Comment: Ah, gotchya :) Ok, tried that. Here's what's happening now: 
1) Go to screen, first cell has white text, yay!
2) Select second cell. First cell text becomes grey, yay! Second cell text is still grey, however. Neither cell's text will switch to white.

Comment: ok - just noticed a typo in my code :-(  when you create `rowToReloadNew` is it with `selectedRowIndexPrevious` - as shown?  that's a mistake, and I'm going to update it now to `selectedRowIndex'

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //change your cell text color here
   cell= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cell.isSelected == YES)
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grey1Color];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Another way is to subclass the tableview cell and implement the following methods:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self updateTextColor:selected];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    [self updateTextColor:highlighted];
}

- (void)updateTextColor:(BOOL)isSelected {
   labelA= //get reference of the cell textlabel
    if (labelA) {
        if (isSelected) {
            [labelA setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        } else {
            [labelA setTextColor:[UIColor greyColor]];
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for this; it's getting me closer! Only difference being that I would need to have the cell white if selected; not grey. 
What's happening now is that if I select a cell, and it's text turns white, and then select another cell, the first cell's text stays white and not grey. Am I missing something?